# HPE HDD differences

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hpe

Where can I find the difference between different HPE drive models?

Specifically, I need to get several 4TB HPE SATA drives for a HPE DL380 server, and I don't understand the difference between a [872491-B21](https://www.senetic.co.uk/product-872491-b21/) 4TB drive, and a [861752-B21](https://www.senetic.co.uk/product-861752-b21/) 4TB drive. I am finding them in different tables and datasheets, but cannot identify the difference, yet the latter is almost 3x more expensive.

What's the difference?

Comment: The difference is the support for 512e format which the second drive has. You should know if you need it or not.

Comment: Make sure you've checked your exact server model's quickspecs to ensure the exact model of drive you want is supported in it too.